# how to create picker view did select row can be passed as parameter for post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, uipickerview

I am new to IOS i need to create parameter for POST method using picker view did select row.

Picker view did select row:

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component

{
    if(pickerView.tag ==2){
    txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([arrmsg1 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }else if(pickerView.tag ==1){
    currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id1 objectAtIndex:row]);

    }
    else
    {
        currency2.text = (NSString *)[from_currency objectAtIndex:row];
        NSLog([id2 objectAtIndex:row]);
    }




}
```

post method:
here str is considered as parameter for post method but i struggling how to call picker view did select row array as my parameter str.

```
-(void) sendDataToServer : (NSString *) method params:(NSString *)str{


    NSData *postData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[str length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if( theConnection ){

        mutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}
```

viewdidload:
coding :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *parseURL =@"Url1";
    NSString *encodeurl =[parseURL stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeurl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if(data){
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:&error];
        arrMsg = [json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.branch_name"];
        //NSLog(@"%@",json);
        arrmsg1 =[json valueForKeyPath:@"Branches.id"];
        firststr = [arrmsg1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@",arrmsg1);


        arrMsg.count!=0;
        if (arrMsg.count >0)
        {
            txtText.text = (NSString *)[arrMsg objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

  //second textfield and third textfield
    NSString *parseURL1 =@"url2";
    NSString *encodeurl1 =[parseURL1 stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:encodeurl1];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    if(data1){
        NSError *error1;
        NSDictionary *json1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options: kNilOptions error:&error1];
        //NSLog(@"%@",json1);
        currencyname1 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.currency_name"];
        id1 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.id"];
        NSLog(@"%@",id1);
        from_currency = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.currency_name"];
        id2 = [json1 valueForKeyPath:@"Currencies.id"];
        secondstr = [id1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        thirdstr = [id2 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"%@",secondstr);
        NSLog(@"%@",thirdstr);

        //NSLog(@"%@",json1);

        currencyname1.count!=0;
        if (currencyname1.count >0)
        {
            currency1.text = (NSString *)[currencyname1 objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        from_currency.count!=0;
        if (from_currency.count >0)
        {
            currency2.text = (NSString *)[from_currency objectAtIndex:0];
        }

    }


    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"branch_id=%@&from_curr=%@&to_curr=%@&value=%@",firststr,secondstr,thirdstr,fourthstr];    

    pktStatePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    pktStatePicker  .delegate = self;

    pktStatePicker  .dataSource = self;
    txtText.delegate = self ;
    currency1.delegate = self;
    currency2.delegate = self;
    [ pktStatePicker  setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
```

Comment: is there any button or click event which click call this `sendDataToServer` method?

Comment: yes is there  button action@Lion

Comment: can you show that the array result of arrmsg1

Comment: 2016-05-10 10:58:31.586 exchange[909:35750] (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
)@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: good, wait for some minutes, show your viewdidload code

Comment: what is id1, id2 and from_currency can you print once

Comment: for id1:2016-05-10 11:06:00.855 exchange[972:39223] (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10,
    11,
    12,
    13,
    14,
    15,
    16,
    17,
    18,
    19,
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25,
    26,
    27,
    28,
    29,
    30,
    31,
    32,
    33,
    34,
    35
)same for id2.@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111488/discussion-between-a-sonu-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

You should set tag to your text fields.

Then on button click you can get text of your textfields and call `sendDataToServer` method from this button click not from did select row.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: But i need picker view selection string as parameter for sendDataToServer@Lion